# Want to increment IP Address String in Loop

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to powershell.  I want to increment the IP address by one.

```
$ipaddress = 15
$NICS = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.IPEnabled -eq “TRUE”}
foreach($NIC in $NICs) {$NIC.EnableStatic("10.0.0.$($ipaddress++)", "255.255.255.0")
            $NIC.SetGateways("10.0.0.1", 1)
            $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("10.0.0.100")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You want to just use `"10.0.0.$ipaddress"` in your static IP declaration, and then on another line later increment it with `$ipaddress++`.

```
$ipaddress = 15
$NICS = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.IPEnabled -eq “TRUE”}
foreach($NIC in $NICs) {$NIC.EnableStatic("10.0.0.$ipaddress", "255.255.255.0")
            $NIC.SetGateways("10.0.0.1", 1)
            $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("10.0.0.100")
            $IPAddress++}
```

Comment: I love when people who know what they are talking about answer my posts.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for? The question was a little ambiguous...I thought that by "I want to increment the IP address by 1", you meant that you wanted to set the IP address to 1 higher than the value of the variable (which I figured came from reading the current IP address somewhere earlier in the script). Are you saying that you want to start from 15, and assign an IP address that's 1 higher to each successive NIC? Either way, see the the part about "voidable statements" in the answer I added. You could just use `$NIC.EnableStatic("10.0.0.$(($ipaddress++))", "255.255.255.0")

Answer (score 2):

With this method you'll at least get an exception if you try to make a BAD IP address. There is plenty of benefits with using the types available in PS. I see the other propose solutions would allow you create something that ends in `256` etc.

```
[IPAddress](([IPAddress]"10.0.0.15").Address + (1 -shl 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Increment operators are [voidable statements](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/powershell-abcs-v-is-for-voidable-statements), which means that they don't produce a return values unless you surround them in parentheses. The **$()** used for string interpolation doesn't count, you need another pair of parentheses within that.
2. When the **++** operator follows the variable, as in `$ipaddress++`, it's a *post*-increment operator, which means that first the variable is evaluated in the expression, then it's incremented. So, even if you get a return result with the second pair of parentheses, you're interpolating the original value of **$ipaddress** into the string, then changing it.

Putting that all together, what you need to do is change

```powershell
foreach ($NIC in $NICs) {$NIC.EnableStatic("10.0.0.$($ipaddress++)", "255.255.255.0")
```

to

```powershell
foreach ($NIC in $NICs) {$NIC.EnableStatic("10.0.0.$((++$ipaddress))", "255.255.255.0")
```

---

**UPDATE**

The wording of the question was ambiguous. I thought that by "I want to increment the IP address by 1", you meant that you want to set the IP address to 1 higher than the value of the variable **$ipaddress** (which I figured would have come from reading the current IP address at some earlier point). If what you mean is that you want to assign increasing IP addresses to each successive NIC, starting from 15, then TheMadTechnician's answer works, but you could also do it more compactly this way, since the source of the problem is that you were interpolating an empty value into the string with `$($ipaddress++)`:

```powershell
foreach ($NIC in $NICs) {$NIC.EnableStatic("10.0.0.$(($ipaddress++))", "255.255.255.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks to weq answer it made me find a way to do a full 8 bytes increment.  I don't know if it is what it is your are looking for but for me it is very useful.

```
# $i being the increment.
[IPAddress](([IPAddress]"192.168.104.0").Address + (($i-band 255) -shl 24) + ((($i -shr 8) -band 255) -shl 16) + ((($i -shr 16) -band 255) -shl 8) + (($i -shr 24) -band 255))
```

Hoping this help.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit annoyed with the answers I've found, they were either too cumbersome or just didn't work.

I finally found the reason, `System.Net.IPAddress.Address()` method, return the bits in a reverse order to how we read it, where the LSB is actually part of the most-significant byte in the address.

```
PS> $ip = '192.168.1.1'

PS> [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($ip).IPAddressToString
192.168.1.1

# Parsing Address, returns the Address in reverse.
PS> [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($ip).Address).IPAddressToString
1.1.168.192
```

And that's why incrementing by 1 never worked (at least for me).

I ended up using the following logic:

```
function Increment-IPAddress{
  param([Parameter(Mandatory)]$ip,$increment = 1)
  [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse(
    [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse(
      [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($ip).Address
    ).Address + $increment
  )
}
```

Example output:

```
# The simplest example
PS> Increment-IPAddress '192.168.1.1' | % IPAddressToString
192.168.1.2

# Passing the threshold between 192.168.1.* and 192.168.2.*
PS> Increment-IPAddress '192.168.1.255' | % IPAddressToString
192.168.2.0

# Some more complex arithmetic:
PS> Increment-IPAddress '192.168.1.254' 3 | % IPAddressToString
192.168.2.1
```

Hope this helps someone looking into this in 2024 onwards