# I need to make script for automatically changing the IP Address on the server every week, and increment the last octet by one

Tags: powershell

```
$ipaddress = 15
$NICS = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
        where {$_.IPEnabled -eq “TRUE”}
foreach ($NIC in $NICs) {
    $NIC.EnableStatic("10.0.0.$($ipaddress++)", "255.255.255.0")
    $NIC.SetGateways("10.0.0.1", 1)
    $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("10.0.0.100")
}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work. I need a command that will read the current static IP and then increment by 1.

Comment: What Windows version are you running? More recent versions provide more convenient cmdlets for working with network adapters and addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact question has been asked before here:
[Want to increment IP Address String in Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834387/want-to-increment-ip-address-string-in-loop)

However, I would approach it a different way with something like this:

```
#Build your array of IP Addresses
$IPAddresses = Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object -Property "IPAddress" -NE 127.0.0.1 | Where-Object -Property "AddressFamily" -EQ IPv4

#Walk through the list of IP addresses
foreach($IPAddress in $IPAddresses)
{
    #DisplayOld addresses
    Write-Host "`nOld IPAddress" $IPAddress.IPv4Address

    $oldIPAddress = $IPAddress.IPv4Address

    #Modify the old IP into the new IPand increment the last octet by 1
    $octets = $IPAddress.IPv4Address.Split(".")
    $octets[3] = [string]([int]$octets[3] + 1)

    $newIPAddress = $octets -join "."


    #DisplayNew IPAddress
    Write-Host "New IPAddress" $newIPAddress

    #Add new IPaddress    ActiveStore
    $make = New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $IPAddress.ifIndex -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress "$newIPAddress" -PrefixLength $IPAddress.PrefixLength 
    #Remove old IPAddress
    $rem = Remove-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $oldIPAddress -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Please consider moving your answer to the other question, as this one should be closed as a duplicate. You may also want to add a note about the minimum requirements for your approach (at least Windows 8 I believe).